# circuit as a theorem box

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

**Is it possible to have a circuit as a theorem-definition box, using `circuits.ee.IEC` or something similar (e.g. `CircuiTikZ`)?**

I want:

- to have a text inside the circuit,
- the circuit's width fixed at `0.8\textwidth` and
- the circuit's height as long as it takes to include all the text,

like this:

[image]

I can't understand the coding, because the [manual](http://www.jobonne.org/compatCircuit.pdf) is in french. I have also made a code for starting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,semithick,
    every info/.style={font=\footnotesize},
    small circuit symbols,
    set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
    \draw (0,0) to [ground={near start, rotate=180}] (0,1)
    to [inductor={direction info={info=$L$},info'=$5H$}] (0,3)
    to [break contact={info=$\delta$}] (2,3)
    to [battery={info={[yshift=-1em]+\quad -},info'={$ 120V $}}] (3,3)
    to [resistor={direction info={info=$R$}, info'=$3\Omega$}] (6,3)
    to [capacitor={info'=$C$, info=$3F$}] (6,1)
    to [ground={near end}] (6,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Looks like fun! Tcolorbox could be a winner for this :)

Comment: @cmhughes , so is it possible to do it with `tcolorbox`? How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tcolorbox`

[image]

You can tweak the positions as you see fit; this version breaks across pages. See [tcolorbox documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for more details.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox{circuitbox}{%
    enhanced jigsaw, breakable, % allow page breaks
    frame hidden, % hide the default frame
    overlay={%
    \begin{scope}[circuit ee IEC,ultra thick,
    every info/.style={font=\normalsize},
    small circuit symbols,
    set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
      \draw
        % left line
        (frame.south west) to [ground={near start, rotate=180}] (frame.west)
        to [inductor={direction info={info=$L$},info'=$5H$}] (frame.north west)
        % top line
        to [break contact={info=$\delta$}] (frame.120)
        to [battery={info={[yshift=-1em]+\quad -},info={$ 120V $}}] (frame.north)
        % right line
        to [resistor={direction info={info=$R$}, info=$3\Omega$}] (frame.north east)
        to [capacitor={info'=$C$, info=$3F$}] (frame.east)
        to [ground={near end}] (frame.south east);
    \end{scope}
    },
    % paragraph skips obeyed within tcolorbox
    parbox=false,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitbox}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{circuitbox}
\begin{circuitbox}
    \lipsum
\end{circuitbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Very clever :)

Comment: @cmhughes , thanks for your answer! I 'm trying to understand your code.
**1)** I changed `semithick` to `ultra thick`, and `\footnotesize` to `normalsize` and nothing happens.
**2)** I can't find how to start with *ground* and not with line.

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας I've updated to use `scope` which addresses your first point. For your second point, if you change `near start` to `at start` I think that should get you close :)

Comment: @cmhughes thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just put the theorem into a node.  I added a minipage in anticipation of problems with the theorem environment.  Otherwise you could simply specify `[text width]`.

Note that labels are not included in the components anchors like (B1.south).  Labels are implemented a separate unnamed nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC,semithick,
    every info/.style={font=\footnotesize},
    small circuit symbols,
    set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
    \draw (0,0) to [ground={near start, rotate=180}] (0,1)
    to [inductor={direction info={info=$L$},info'=$5H$}] (0,3)
    to [break contact={info=$\delta$}] (2,3)
    to [battery={info={[yshift=-1em]+\quad -},info'={$ 120V $},name=B1}] (3,3)
    to [resistor={direction info={info=$R$}, info'=$3\Omega$}] (6,3)
    to [capacitor={info'=$C$, info=$3F$}] (6,1)
    to [ground={near end}] (6,0);
    \node[below=\baselineskip] at (current bounding box.center |- B1.south) {\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
      There really isn't much room in here, so you might want to increase the dimensions 
      of the circuit.
    \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I also prefer the `tcolorbox` solution, rather than `tikz` (although I understand it better), because it has problems with long texts. The text goes out of ground limits.